# bash howto script - if no answer or mutliline answer

Tags: bash, test

I have a script, that reads some input `foo`, and based on that input tries to calculate the value for the variable `bar`. If it is successful, then it shall set `bar`. If not, the user should be able to input that value for `bar` manually.

Currently I have:

```
read foo
bar=$(some manipulation with foo)
if [ $bar ]
then 
  echo $bar
else
  read bar
fi
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that in some cases I get more than a single word answer back from the manipulation of foo. I know I could work around that with quotes or the new test, but that's not what I want. I'd like that if `some manipulation with foo` returns multiline output, that it asks to set `bar` manually. The same reaction as to no answer. How would I do that?

Comment: Is it a question about words or lines? If you get a line with many word in `bar`, is it accepted?

Comment: one line with many words would be inacceptable. But that won't happen. it's always one word per line max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the array size of bar:

```
#!/bin/bash

read foo
bar=(${foo})

case ${#bar[@]} in
  0) echo "bar has 0 words" ;;
  1) echo "bar has 1 word" ;;
  *) echo "bar has > 1 words" ;;
esac
```

Depending of the input you get the information how many words bar contains. The `${#bar[@]}` gives the number of elements bar contains.

Comment: thanks, that's almost it. so what I needed to do is replace `if [ $bar ]` with `if [ ${#bar[@]} == 1 ]`. Awesome.

Comment: Beware that if `foo` is `'*'` for instance, `$bar` will contain the names of all the files in the current directory.

Comment: And, I think this is not working for multiline texts. This is working for a single line with many words; is this the requested behaviour?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas is `set -f;read foo;set +f` the common way to prevent globbing?

Comment: @bersch, no you need the `set -f` in effect in `bar=($foo)`, that is when you use the split+glob operator (leaving a variable expansion unquoted) and only want the split part. `read` doesn't do globbing.

Comment: @eppesuig, `bar=($foo)` splits based on the current value of `$IFS`. The default value of `$IFS` has space, tab and newline. So it will give you all the words of every line.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas right, so you will have a counter of words, while I think the question is about a counter of lines.

Comment: @eppesuig, yes, the question is unclear on that front. Note that the OP used the split+glob operator in his question when leaving the `$bar` unquoted in `[ $bar ]` (which I agree does not make sense)

Answer (score 1):

With any Bourne-like shell:

```
case $bar in
  "" | *[!$IFS]*[$IFS]*[!$IFS]*) echo empty or multi-word;;
  *) echo OK
esac
```

Or:

```
set -f
set -- $bar
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
   echo OK
else
   echo empty of multi-word, words being:
   printf '  "%s"\n' "$@"
fi
```

Set IFS to the *word* separator. For instance, if words are meant to be non-empty lines:

```
IFS='
'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just have a small function that check for that. This is an example, with a few tests:

```
empty_or_multiline()
{
  [ -z "$1" ] && return 0
  count=$(echo "$1" | wc -l)
  [ $count -gt 1 ] && return 0

  return 1
}

# test number 1
bar=
if empty_or_multiline "$bar"
then
  echo Empty or multiline
else
  echo bar="$bar"
fi

# test number 2
bar=jajhsflgkh
if empty_or_multiline "$bar"
then
  echo Empty or multiline
else
  echo bar="$bar"
fi

# test number 3
bar="kjh\nskjfjhgf"
if empty_or_multiline "$bar"
then
  echo Empty or multiline
else
  echo bar="$bar"
fi
```

Comment: Note that the outcome of test 3 will depend on the implementation of `echo` and for `bash` on the environment and/or how `bash` was compiled. See [Why is printf better than echo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/22565) for details.